# VBA to move through slicer one by one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with raw data. I want to code a macro that will create a splicer with the header Engine No., then select slicer #1, and then copy all the data that is visible in the data to another sheet. Consecutively, move to slicer #2 and repeat the steps of copying the filtered data to another sheet.

This is what I got from the macro recorder. This is not what I can use because the numbers will be different in a new data sheet. I was thinking of using a loop. Is there a better way other than a loop? I need to copy what is displayed to another sheet for every slicer item.

I also saw `SlicerItems` and `SlicerCache`, but I don't know what they are. Could anybody explain to me what they are?

```
Sub slicer()

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Engine_S_N.")
    .SlicerItems("123456").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("123441").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("123123").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("235455").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("566346").Selected = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub IterateSlices()
    Dim CurrentSlice As Integer
    For CurrentSlice = 1 To 3
        SelectOnly ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Engine_S_N."), CurrentSlice
        MsgBox "Do Something here"
    Next
End Sub

Sub SelectOnly(Slicer As SlicerCache, SliceNo As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    ' Force at least one to be selected before start
    Slicer.SlicerItems(Slicer.SlicerItems.Count).Selected = True

    For i = 1 To Slicer.SlicerItems.Count
        Debug.Print (SliceNo = i)
        Slicer.SlicerItems(i).Selected = (SliceNo = i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The last method is utility method that selects the nth SliceItem. It is easier to work with index numbers rather than names. They always start with number 1 and end with the number of slices.

The first method picks one slice at a time.

SlicerCache is Excel's internal mechanism of keeping track of which data that belongs to which slice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me a lot. I have a question, now if i want to add some filters before running through the slicer do i create a new sub and put it before `option explicit`? And do I replace `msgbox` with the code for the task which i need to do in between slicers?

Comment: Yes, replace the MsgBox with the thing you want to do for each slice. Whether you create a new sub for this or if you put inside the loop is up to you. If you create a sub, you have isolated that part, and you can test it separately. The Sub can be placed anywhere, as long as it is between other Subs and Functions - not inside them.